# Unix - Searching for every file with a certain string in it

Tags: unix, grep, find

I am searching for every file within a root directory and want to search every subdirectory as well. I have tried

```
grep -r "message" *
```

but I am not sure that this searches every subdirectory, any suggestions?

Comment: Have tou tried it ? It's recursive as well. No need a wildcard `*`, a  dot `.` is sufficient (current dir)

Comment: my main suggestion in this case is, you should read the manual.

Comment: I have tried it, it only comes up with one instance which doesnt make any sense so I was wondering if maybe its only searching the direct subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

[ack](/questions/tagged/ack) or [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) can both do it easily & fits your needs as well :

```
ack -r "pattern"
```

or

```
grep -r "pattern" .
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do with find command also.
I have written in my blog [post](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/06/19/find-command-to-search-keyword-in-files-recursively-in-linux/)

If you are looking for exact match of keyword with grep command you can read my another [post](http://sharadchhetri.com/2013/06/19/how-to-use-grep-command-to-get-fixed-pattern-or-exact-keyword/) I wrote this both post today